# WebGL camera object doesn't seem to follow character

Tags: javascript, 3d, camera

I've been following instructions for game development using webGL from [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/General/9781849699792), and in the chapter about cameras, it discusses and gives a very limited example of an orbital camera, but goes on to continue the rest of the book focusing on a simple first-person, free camera.

The orbital camera works very well, but if I try to create a controllable character object, and set the camera's orbit point to follow it, the camera seems to... get ahead of itself? It somehow moves faster than the character.

Here's the relevant method from the OrbitalCamera object:

```
OrbitCamera.prototype.setOrbitPoint = function (orbitPoint)
{
  // get the distance the camera was from the orbit point.
    var orbitPointToCam =vec3.create();
    vec3.multiply(orbitPointToCam,this.dir, -this.getDistance());
    this.orbitPoint[0] = orbitPoint[0];
    this.orbitPoint[1] = orbitPoint[1];
    this.orbitPoint[2] = orbitPoint[2];
    vec3.add(this.pos,this.orbitPoint, orbitPointToCam);
}
```

And here is where the function is being called:

```
                function animate(){
                var lSpeed = 0;
                var uSpeed = 0;
                var distance = cam.getDistance();

                if(stage.stageObjects.length != 0){
                var pos = stage.stageObjects[0].location;

                    if (left) {
                        lSpeed = +0.05;
                    }
                    if (right) {
                        lSpeed = -0.05;
                    }
                    if (up) {
                        uSpeed = 0.05;
                    }
                    if (down) {
                        uSpeed = -0.05;
                    }   

                    stage.stageObjects[0].location = [(uSpeed*Math.round(cam.dir[0]))+(lSpeed*Math.round(cam.left[0]))+pos[0], pos[1], (uSpeed*Math.round(cam.dir[2]))+(lSpeed*Math.round(cam.left[2]))+pos[2]]
                    cam.setOrbitPoint([stage.stageObjects[0].location[0],0,stage.stageObjects[0].location[2]]);
                    cam.setDistance(distance);                        

                    if (cup) {
                        cam.pitch(Math.PI*0.01);   
                    }
                    if (cdown) {
                        cam.pitch(-Math.PI*0.01);   
                    }
                    if (cleft) {
                        cam.yaw(-Math.PI*0.01);   
                    }
                    if (cright) {
                        cam.yaw(Math.PI*0.01);   
                    }

                }


            }
```

And here is the draw call:

```
                function drawScene(){
                gl.viewport(0,0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

                setLightUniform();

                pushMatrix();
                calculateMvMatrix();
                for (var i = 0; i<stage.stageObjects.length; i++){

                    pushMatrix();
                    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, stage.stageObjects[i].location);
                    mat4.rotateX(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, stage.stageObjects[i].rotationX);
                    mat4.rotateY(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, stage.stageObjects[i].rotationY);
                    mat4.rotateZ(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, stage.stageObjects[i].rotationZ);
                    setMatrixUniforms();

                    gl.uniform3f(shaderProgram.materialDiffuseColor, stage.stageObjects[i].diffuseColor[0],stage.stageObjects[i].diffuseColor[1],stage.stageObjects[i].diffuseColor[2]);
                    gl.uniform3f(shaderProgram.materialAmbientColor, stage.stageObjects[i].ambientColor[0],stage.stageObjects[i].ambientColor[1],stage.stageObjects[i].ambientColor[2]);

                    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, stage.stageObjects[i].vbo);
                    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, stage.stageObjects[i].vbo.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, stage.stageObjects[i].nbo);
                    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, stage.stageObjects[i].nbo.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);

                    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, stage.stageObjects[i].ibo);
                    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, stage.stageObjects[i].geometry.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
                    popMatrix();
                }
                popMatrix();



            }
```

I can post the whole code for the Camera object if the problem isn't in here. Any help is greatly appreciated, this has been driving me crazy

Comment: Can you explain what `stage.stageObjects[0].location = [(uSpeed*Math.round(cam.dir[0]))+(lSpeed*Math.round(cam.left[0]))+pos[0], pos[1], (uSpeed*Math.round(cam.dir[2]))+(lSpeed*Math.round(cam.left[2]))+pos[2]]`  is trying to do?

Comment: For sure, that's me handling the controls for the character. uSpeed is the movement along the Z axis, cam.dir and cam.left are the "look" and "left" axis of the camera, and pos holds the coordinates of the player object

Comment: I dont think that is the correct. If your `camera.dir` and `camera.left` are normalized vectors then you shouldnt need `Math.round`. If they are not normalized vectors then `Math.round` wouldnt make them normalized. It really should be, in vector form: `pos + normalized(camera.dir) * uSpeed + normalized(camera.left) * lSpeed`.